# Implement RGBtoHSV C++ , wrong H output

Tags: c++, image, c++11, image-processing

I am trying to do Sobel operator in the HSV dimension (told to do this in the HSV by my guide  but I dont understand why it will work better on HSV than on RGB) .
I have built a function that converts from RGB to HSV .  while I have some mediocre knowledge in C++ I am getting confused by the Image Processing thus I tried to keep the code as simple as possible , meaning I dont care (at this stage) about time nor space .
From looking on the results I got in gray levels bmp photos , my V and S seems to be fine but my H looks very gibbrish .
I got 2 questions here :
1. How a normal H photo in gray level should look a like comparing to the source photo ?
2. Where was I wrong in the code :

```
   void RGBtoHSV(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS],
float Him[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
float Vim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], 
float Sim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{

double Rn, Gn, Bn;

double   C;
double H, S, V;

for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        Rn = (1.0*image[row][column][R]) / 255;
        Gn = (1.0*image[row][column][G] )/ 255;
        Bn = (1.0*image[row][column][B] )/ 255;

        //double RGBn[3] = { Rn, Gn, Bn };

        double max = Rn;
        if (max < Gn) max = Gn;
        if (max < Bn) max = Bn;
        double min = Rn;
        if (min > Gn) min = Gn;
        if (min > Bn) min = Bn;

        C = max - min;

        H = 0;
        if (max==0)
        {
            S = 0;
            H = -1; //undifined;
            V = max;
        }
        else
        {

        /*  if (max == Rn)
                H = (60.0* ((int)((Gn - Bn) / C) % 6));
            else if (max == Gn)
                H = 60.0*( (Bn - Rn)/C + 2);
            else
                H = 60.0*( (Rn - Gn)/C + 4);
            */

            if (max == Rn)
                H = (   60.0* ( (Gn - Bn) / C) )   ;
            else if (max == Gn)
                H = 60.0*((Bn - Rn) / C + 2);
            else
                H = 60.0*((Rn - Gn) / C + 4);

            V = max; //AKA lightness
            S = C / max; //saturation 
        }


        while (H < 0) 
            H += 360;
        while (H>360) 
            H -= 360;

        Him[row][column] = (float)H;

        Vim[row][column] = (float)V;
        Sim[row][column] = (float)S;
    }
}
}
```

also my hsvtorgb :

```
void HSVtoRGB(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS],
float Him[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
float Vim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
float Sim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{

double R1, G1, B1;

double   C;
double   V;
double S;
double H;
int Htag;
double Htag2;
double x;
double m;

for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        H = (double)Him[row][column];
        S = (double)Sim[row][column];
        V = (double)Vim[row][column];


        C = V*S;

        Htag = (int) (H / 60.0);
        Htag2 = H/ 60.0;


        //x = C*(1 - abs(Htag % 2 - 1));
        double tmp1 = fmod(Htag2, 2);
        double temp=(1 - abs(tmp1 - 1));
        x = C*temp;
        //switch (Htag)
        switch (Htag)
        {
        case 0 : 
            R1 = C;
            G1 = x;
            B1 = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            R1 = x;
            G1 = C;
            B1 = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            R1 = 0;
            G1 = C;
            B1 = x;
            break;
        case 3:
            R1 = 0;
            G1 = x;
            B1 = C;
            break;
        case 4:
            R1 = x;
            G1 = 0;
            B1 = C;
            break;
        case 5:
            R1 = C;
            G1 = 0;
            B1 = x;
            break;
        default:
            R1 = 0;
            G1 = 0;
            B1 = 0;
            break;

        }


        m = V - C;
   //this is also good change I found
        //image[row][column][R] = unsigned char( (R1 + m)*255);
        //image[row][column][G] = unsigned char( (G1 + m)*255);
        //image[row][column][B] = unsigned char( (B1 + m)*255);

        image[row][column][R] = round((R1 + m) * 255);
        image[row][column][G] = round((G1 + m) * 255);
        image[row][column][B] = round((B1 + m) * 255);



            }
      }
   }


   void HSVfloattoGrayconvert(unsigned char grayimage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS]        [NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], float hsvimage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], char hsv)
  {
//grayimage , flaotimage , h/s/v
   float factor;
if (hsv == 'h' || hsv == 'H') factor = (float) 1 / 360;
else factor = 1;
for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        grayimage[row][column] = (unsigned char) (0.5f + 255.0f * (float)hsvimage[row][column] / factor);
          }
      }
 }
```

and my main:

```
 unsigned char ColorImage1[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]   [NUMBER_OF_COLORS];
float Himage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
float Vimage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
float Simage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

 unsigned char ColorImage2[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]   [NUMBER_OF_COLORS];

unsigned char HimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char VimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char SimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

unsigned char HAfterSobel[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char VAfterSobel[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char SAfterSobal[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

   unsigned char HSVcolorAfterSobal[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS];

unsigned char RGBAfterSobal[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS];


int KernelX[3][3] = { 
{-1,0,+1}, {-2,0,2}, {-1,0,1 }
};

  int KernelY[3][3] = {
   {-1,-2,-1}, {0,0,0}, {1,2,1}
  };

  void main()
{

//work
LoadBgrImageFromTrueColorBmpFile(ColorImage1, "P22A.bmp");

// add noise
AddSaltAndPepperNoiseRGB(ColorImage1, 350, 255);
StoreBgrImageAsTrueColorBmpFile(ColorImage1, "saltandpepper.bmp");
AddGaussNoiseCPPstileRGB(ColorImage1, 0.0, 1.0);
StoreBgrImageAsTrueColorBmpFile(ColorImage1, "Saltandgauss.bmp");

//saves hsv in float array 
RGBtoHSV(ColorImage1, Himage, Vimage, Simage); 

//saves hsv float arrays in unsigned char arrays
HSVfloattoGrayconvert(HimageGray, Himage, 'h');
HSVfloattoGrayconvert(VimageGray, Vimage, 'v');
HSVfloattoGrayconvert(SimageGray, Simage, 's');


StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(HimageGray, "P22H.bmp");
StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(VimageGray, "P22V.bmp");
StoreGrayImageAsGrayBmpFile(SimageGray, "P22S.bmp");

    WaitForUserPressKey();

  }
```

edit : Changed Code + add sources for equations :
Soruce : for equations :

5. http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm
6. http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm

edit3:
listening to [@gpasch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5634769/gpasch) advice and using [better reference](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html)  and deleting the mod6 I am now able to restore the RGB original photo!!! but unfortunately now my H photo in grayscale is even more chaotic than before .
I'll edit the code about so it will have more info about how I am saving the H grayscale photo .

Comment: For a grayscale image, S (saturation) should be zero and H (hue) is undefined, or takes on some canonical angle bacause its value (an angle on the color wheel) doesn't make sense for shades of gray.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles ok to set S to 0 but what about H ?  I'll add another piece of code which might be problematic also

Comment: `C == 0` means the pixel is black, white or gray.  `H` has no meaning in this case, so it is arbitrarily set to `0`, just to give these cases a consistent value for `H`.

Comment: where did you get the equations for the conversion?

Comment: @gpasch from :

5. http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm 
6. http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm 

also ill add in edit this soruces

Comment: @Maor If H is undefined you can also set it to zero without any problems. (Thanks to Christopher Oicles for his very good comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to do Sobel operator in the HSV dimension (told to do this in the HSV by my guide but I dont understand why it will work better on HSV than on RGB)

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you're trying to do edge detection based on brightness for example, then just working with say the V channel might be simpler than processing all three channels of RGB and combining them afterwards.

> 1. How a normal H photo in gray level should look a like comparing to the source photo ?

You would see regions which are a similar colour appear as a similar shade of grey, and for a real-world scene you would still see gradients. But where there are spatially adjacent regions with colours far apart in hue, there would be a sharp jump.  The shapes would generally be recognisable though.

> 2. Where was I wrong in the code :

There are two main problems with your code. The first is that the hue scaling in `HSVfloattoGrayconvert` is wrong. Your code is setting `factor=1.0/360.0f` but then *dividing* by the factor, which means it's multiplying by 360. If you simply multiply by the factor, it produces the expected output. This is because the earlier calculation uses normalised values (0..1) for S and V but angle in degrees for H, so you need to divide by 360 to normalise H.

Second, the conversion back to RGB has a problem, mainly to do with calculating `Htag` where you want the original value for calculating `x` but the `floor` only when switching on the sector.

Note that despite what @gpasch suggested, the `mod 6` operation is actually correct. This is because the conversion you are using is based on the hexagonal colour space model for HSV, and this is used to determine which sector your colour is in.  For a continuous model, you could use a radial conversion instead which is slightly different. Both are well explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

I took your code, added a few functions to generate input data and save output files so it is completely standalone, and fixed the bugs above while making minimal changes to the source.

Given the following generated input image:

[image: Generated source image - colour wash]

the Hue channel extracted is:

[image: Hue channel]

The saturation channel is:

[image: Saturation channel]

and finally value:

[image]

After fixing up the HSV to RGB conversion, I verified that the resulting output image matches the original.

The updated code is below (as mentioned above, changed minimally to make a standalone test):

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

enum ColorIndex
{
    R = 0,
    G = 1,
    B = 2,
};

namespace
{
    const unsigned NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS   = 256;
    const unsigned NUMBER_OF_ROWS      = 256;
    const unsigned NUMBER_OF_COLORS    = 3;
};

void RGBtoHSV(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS],
              float Him[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
              float Vim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
              float Sim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{
    double Rn, Gn, Bn;
    double   C;
    double H, S, V;

    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            Rn = image[row][column][R] / 255.0;
            Gn = image[row][column][G] / 255.0;
            Bn = image[row][column][B] / 255.0;

            double max = Rn;
            if (max < Gn) max = Gn;
            if (max < Bn) max = Bn;
            double min = Rn;
            if (min > Gn) min = Gn;
            if (min > Bn) min = Bn;

            C = max - min;

            H = 0;
            if (max==0)
            {
                S = 0;
                H = 0; // Undefined
                V = max;
            }
            else
            {
                if (max == Rn)
                    H = 60.0*fmod((Gn - Bn) / C, 6.0);
                else if (max == Gn)
                    H = 60.0*((Bn - Rn) / C + 2);
                else
                    H = 60.0*((Rn - Gn) / C + 4);

                V = max; //AKA lightness
                S = C / max; //saturation
            }


            while (H < 0)
                H += 360.0;
            while (H > 360)
                H -= 360.0;

            Him[row][column] = (float)H;
            Vim[row][column] = (float)V;
            Sim[row][column] = (float)S;
        }
    }
}

void HSVtoRGB(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS],
              float Him[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
              float Vim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS],
              float Sim[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{

    double R1, G1, B1;

    double   C;
    double   V;
    double S;
    double H;
    double Htag;
    double x;
    double m;

    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            H = (double)Him[row][column];
            S = (double)Sim[row][column];
            V = (double)Vim[row][column];

            C = V*S;

            Htag = H / 60.0;

            double x = C*(1.0 - fabs(fmod(Htag, 2.0) - 1.0));

            int i = floor(Htag);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0 :
                    R1 = C;
                    G1 = x;
                    B1 = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    R1 = x;
                    G1 = C;
                    B1 = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    R1 = 0;
                    G1 = C;
                    B1 = x;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    R1 = 0;
                    G1 = x;
                    B1 = C;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    R1 = x;
                    G1 = 0;
                    B1 = C;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    R1 = C;
                    G1 = 0;
                    B1 = x;
                    break;
                default:
                    R1 = 0;
                    G1 = 0;
                    B1 = 0;
                    break;

            }

            m = V - C;

            image[row][column][R] = round((R1 + m) * 255);
            image[row][column][G] = round((G1 + m) * 255);
            image[row][column][B] = round((B1 + m) * 255);
        }
    }
}


void HSVfloattoGrayconvert(unsigned char grayimage[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], float hsvimage[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], char hsv)
{
//grayimage , flaotimage , h/s/v
    float factor;
    if (hsv == 'h' || hsv == 'H') factor = 1.0f/360.0f;
    else factor = 1.0f;
    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            grayimage[row][column] = (unsigned char) (0.5f + 255.0f * (float)hsvimage[row][column] * factor);
        }
    }
}


int KernelX[3][3] = {
    {-1,0,+1}, {-2,0,2}, {-1,0,1 }
};

int KernelY[3][3] = {
    {-1,-2,-1}, {0,0,0}, {1,2,1}
};

void GenerateTestImage(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS])
{
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; y++)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; x++)
        {
            image[y][x][R] = x % 256;
            image[y][x][G] = y % 256;
            image[y][x][B] = (255-x) % 256;
        }
    }
}

void GenerateTestImage(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS])
{
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; y++)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; x++)
        {
            image[x][y] = x % 256;
        }
    }
}

// Color (three channel) images
void SaveImage(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS], const std::string& filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n%u %u\n255\n", NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
    fwrite(image, NUMBER_OF_COLORS, NUMBER_OF_ROWS*NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

// Grayscale (single channel) images
void SaveImage(unsigned char image[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], const std::string& filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%u %u\n255\n", NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
    fwrite(image, 1, NUMBER_OF_ROWS*NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

unsigned char ColorImage1[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS][NUMBER_OF_COLORS];
unsigned char Himage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char Simage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
unsigned char Vimage[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
float HimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
float SimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
float VimageGray[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

int main()
{
    // Test input
    GenerateTestImage(ColorImage1);
    SaveImage(ColorImage1, "test_input.ppm");

    //saves hsv in float array
    RGBtoHSV(ColorImage1, HimageGray, VimageGray, SimageGray);

    //saves hsv float arrays in unsigned char arrays
    HSVfloattoGrayconvert(Himage, HimageGray, 'h');
    HSVfloattoGrayconvert(Vimage, VimageGray, 'v');
    HSVfloattoGrayconvert(Simage, SimageGray, 's');

    SaveImage(Himage, "P22H.pgm");
    SaveImage(Vimage, "P22V.pgm");
    SaveImage(Simage, "P22S.pgm");

    // Convert back to get the original test image
    HSVtoRGB(ColorImage1, HimageGray, VimageGray, SimageGray);
    SaveImage(ColorImage1, "test_output.ppm");

    return 0;
}
```

The input image was generated by a very simple algorithm which gives us gradients in each dimension, so we can easily inspect and verify the expected output. I used `ppm/pgm` files as they are simpler to write and more portable than BMP.

Hope this helps - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

That is the peril of going through garbage web sites; I suggest the following:

https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

That mod 6 seems fishy there.

You also need to make sure you understand that H is in degrees from 0 to 360; if your filter expects 0..1 you have the change.

Comment: you were right about the mod 6 . I deleted it and now my converted back image to rgb looks like the original ! thanks a lot !.
but now the H photo in gray scale looks like total garbage
[Original photo](http://i.imgur.com/begaSdd.png?1)
[Hphoto](http://i.imgur.com/EOU5Hpe.png?1)

Comment: I'm glad someone with patience was finally able to figure this out.

Comment: The `mod 6` is fine, actually - it arises from the hexagonal nature of the colour space. The problem with H was with the normalisation scaling.